# Efficient storage of array of objects holding primitives in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays

What is the most efficient way to convert the following data structure from C to Java?

```
struct {
  int a; int b; int c; int d;
  double e;
} foo[] = {
  { 0, 1, 2, 42, 37.972},
  /* ... 100 more struct elements ... */,
  { 0, 3, -1, -4, -7.847}
}
```

I best I could think of is this:

```
class Foo {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
    public double e;
    public Foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, double e) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }
}

Foo[] foo = new Foo[] {
    new Foo(0, 1, 2, 42, 37.972),
    /* ... 100 more objects ... */
    new Foo(0, 3, -1, -4, -7.847)
}
```

But it uses way too many objects for holding simple primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it uses way too many objects for holding simple primitives.

No, it doesn't. A Java `int` or `double` field is not an object; it will be allocated on the heap as part of its containing `Foo` instance.

So in your case there will be 101 objects: one `Foo[]` array, and 100 `Foo` instances.

Or do you want all of that to be a single "flat" array? Sorry, no can do in Java, that's not how it works.

Then again, what exactly are you worrying about here? 101 Objects of this kind are *nothing*, we're talking about less than 4KB here!

Comment: Yes, I hoped I could make it flat instead of using 101 objects. This is so simple to do in C.

Comment: @Dheeraj: well, if you want C, you know where to find it... Seriously, where's the problem? An Object has an overhead of 8 bytes. Since your example objects have 24 bytes payload, that's 33% overhead. Not perfect, but hardly dramatic, and certainly not worth worrying about unless you have millions of objects (and even then, finding a way to reduce that number could be far more effective).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Coming from an embedded C background, I was paranoid.

Comment: @Dheeraj: Ah, that explains it :)

Answer (score 2):

Using 5 parallel arrays is probably the most memory-effective way you can manage that.

**But** it will be **much** more complicated to handle and you can far too easily introduce bugs, apart from it not being very OO-like (i.e. you can't easily make use of the usefull features Java provides with such a construct).

So I'd *only* attempt to go that way, if the *obvious* mapping (create a class and create an array of that type) can be *proven* to be problematic.

*If* you use the parallel arrays approach, then you could create a `Foo` class that acts as a facade object to those arrays: it takes an index `i` and acts as if it was a single struct by transparently referencing the appropriate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In your C array of structs, you'd select which row you want first, then which column (a, b, c, d, e). You could use similar storage space in Java by using a separate array for each column:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 0, ..., 0 };
int[] b = new int[] { 1, ..., 3 };
int[] c = new int[] { 2, ..., -1 };
int[] d = new int[] { 42, ..., -4 };
double[] e = new double[] { 37.972, ..., -7.847 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing your question : "The storage of array of objects holding primitives in Java IS Efficient". You shouldn't even ask yourself such questions : arrays, and collections, and objects, are the way to go, use them without an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: Don't worry about it.

The size of a Foo object in a 32-bit JVM is

8 bytes object overhead + 4 * (4 bytes for int fields) + 1 * (8 byte for double fields) = 32 bytes

So the object overhead is 25%. There are ways to use memory efficiently with Java NIO buffers, but it's rarely worth while unless you're dealing with massive amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be a problem. The class is not so much bigger than the space needed for its fields. You could of course use an array to store all values but then you have to search through the array to find something.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up a online converter or write a simple program which uses regexp to capture the data from c source file and generate java code.